# How to extract date and time in hive

Tags: hive

I want to extract date and time which is in unixformat.

Example: I have a date field in HDFS file. I want to extract `date` field

```
-2016:08:12 13:22:11:7897669
```

I want `date` as

```
2016:08:12 13:22:11
```

Anybody has answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SUBSTR(datefield,1,19);`

1 is the starting position and upto 19 character it will display..